# Ajax data parameter to php file on external domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, mobile, parameters

In this file called like this :

/fichier_clients/fiche_client.html?id=4870

It used "id" value and make a request to external file (php). 
Data doesn't pass to php file (external domain).
Distant php file execute fine with no error and resend extract. 
Data from database with **test id**, 
but not with value received via ajax -> params: {"term": id},

```
  <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
  function fiche0()
  {
      var id = location.search; 
      var id = id.split('='); 
      var id = id[1];   
      alert (id);
      var encoded = encodeURIComponent('http://www.mydomain.fr/connexion.php');

      $.ajax({
    url: 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url='+encoded,
    type:'POST',
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain:true,
    params: {"term": id},
    timeout: 4000
    }).done(function(reponse){
         a=reponse.contents.split(';'); 
              document.getElementById("client").innerHTML = a[0] ;
              document.getElementById("adresse1").innerHTML = a[1] ;
      })


  }


  window.onload = fiche;
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot POST to an external domain, only GET requests pass data to external.

I would suggest using $_REQUEST in your php script as opposed to $_POST, this way you can see all data coming in regardless of how it was sent.

Answer (score 0):

in this case I can send data, but no return

---

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function get_XmlHttp() {
    // create the variable that will contain the instance of the XMLHttpRequest object (initially with null value)
    var xmlHttp = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {        // for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) {    // for Internet Explorer 5 or 6
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlHttp;
  }
  // sends data to a php file, via GET, and displays the received answer
  function ajaxrequest(pid) {
    var request =  get_XmlHttp();        // call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance

    // create the URL with data that will be sent to the server (a pair index=value)
    var  url = 'http://www.mydomain.fr/connexion.php?term=3334';

    request.open("GET", url, true);            // define the request
    request.send(null);        // sends data

    // Check request status
    // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
          alert ("toto");
        document.getElementById("context").innerHTML = request.responseText;
      }
    }
  }


    window.onload = ajaxrequest;
  </script>

  <div id="context"></div>
```